# Detect browser support of external svg for the use element?

Tags: javascript, svg, cross-browser, feature-detection

I am looking for a way to test if a browser can have an external svg reference in the `use` element:

```
<svg>
    <use xlink:href="sprite.svg#icon-name"></use>
</svg>
```

This works in most modern browsers, but does not work in browsers like IE11 or Edge. Instead of testing to see if a browsers "name" is "x", I would rather use "feature detection" to know if I need to run a fallback.

I can't access the `use`'s Shadow DOM to see if an external reference was placed inside of it, and I don't think I can detect if "content" was actually placed in a temporary element referencing an external svg.

For example, I can't set up an element in this way:

```
var svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');

var use = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'use');
use.setAttributeNS(
    'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink',
    'xlink:href', 
    'sprite.svg#icon-name'
);

svg.appendChild(use);
document.body.appendChild(svg);

// Somehow test to see if it worked...

document.body.appendChild(svg);
```

Is there actually a way to feature detect this, or will I have to go with detecting browser "name"?

Comment: Perhaps the script linked at http://stackoverflow.com/a/33706558/5285945 will provide a clue?