# Load SVG's through image tag and be able to change it's color without fetching inline SVG with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

For the company I work at, I am required to load in SVG's for a web application. The SVG's are in components that consist of HTML code. These components are loaded into a bigger HTML structure. Each component can have a different SVG icon and it must be easy to change. It's color must also be able to be changed through CSS.

I can **not** write down inline SVG, because administrators must be able to easily change the image (e.g.: from `https://example.com/svg/potato.svg` to `https://example.com/svg/carrot.svg`. I can also **not** use any AJAX/fetch related functions to fetch the inline SVG, as the component must be able to run perfectly on the test domain, which will trigger CORS errors. Changing the CORS settings is not an option for this application.

My only option left is to load all SVG's (10 at the moment, but could scale anytime) and to look for the right one, depending on the user inputted svg name. I could make the user call a JS function like this: `showSVG('carrot');`, but I'd rather not load all SVG's for the sake of loadtime.

Some answers tell you to use CSS `filter`, but that requires the user to probably look up the correct filters for the correct hex code. I'd just like the user to be able to write the CSS like this: `fill: #eee;`
I also checked out CSS `mask`, but that has [ok-ish](https://caniuse.com/#search=mask) support, so I'd rather not use that right now.

Here is an example of what I'd like to achieve:

**HTML**

```
<div class="img">
        <img src="https://example.com/svg/carrot.svg" alt="">
        <p>Test component</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.img {
  fill: yellow; 
}
```

I'm open for the hackiest Javascript solutions, as long as they are available for every browser.

Comment: `filter` may not have the effect you want as it changes every color in the image not just a particular area, but it's the only thing I can think of right now. If you want to use it but want the user to be able to easily change the color then just make a js function that acts like a middle man: the user uses the function like `changeImageColor("#ff0000")` and the function does the complicated work by using `theImage.style.filter = ...`.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir The image is supposed to be one color, so that's fine. I guess the function would work out, but I'm afraid that the filter might not be effective. Some of the `hex to filter` functions I've seen, aren't that accurate. Could you show me a good one?

Comment: Is it possible to know the color used in the original image?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I can change the default color to anything required.

Comment: Can you use the HSL color system like `changeImageColor(hue, saturation, luminance)` instead of RGB or HEX?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Unfortunately not. My boss wants the end users to only have to input a hex code.

Comment: This https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp looks promising

Comment: What about SVG to HTML canvas and doing the color alteration there? [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/b1rgp2uc/), source [tristandunn.com](https://tristandunn.com/2014/01/24/rendering-svg-on-canvas/)

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir The issue is that with certain colors there are up to 10% color inaccuracies. There are quite a few components next to each other so they have to be the same color and the exact color (or 99% correct) as the user inputs.

Comment: @thishandle Thank you for your example, but this doesn't seem to work in Firefox for some reason.

Comment: @thishandle Correction: It does work, but only half of the image loads and the lines aren't smooth.

Comment: Have you considered storing them as external files but using some kind of server-side include function so they can be affected by the page's stylesheet?

Comment: @Kravimir That would be a nice solution, but I can't change anything in the backend. I can only change the front end.

Answer (score 1):

Modern browsers can do this without JS by making use of the SVG `<use>` element. However, I recommend using a JS shim like [svgxuse](https://github.com/Keyamoon/svgxuse/), for older browsers, including IE11.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
img {
    border: 2px solid black;
}
svg {
    border: 2px solid goldenrod;
}

svg[class*=fill-] {
    font-size:56px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    /* When using the <use> element, you need to set the styles in the page, 
    but when loading it as a regular image, styles set within the SVG file will be used. 

    Be careful about using inline styles to set any colors, since those will override others. */
}
svg.fill-blue {
    color: blue;
    fill: currentColor;
}
svg.fill-green {
    color: green;
    fill: currentColor;
}
svg.fill-orange {
    fill: orange; /* the currentColor value trick is optional */
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<img src="external-svg-example.svg" alt="">

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="720" height="90">
<image xlink:href="external-svg-example.svg" width="720" height="90"/>
</svg>

<!-- It may be desirable to place the xmlns:xlink attribute in the <html> tag instead of each <svg> tag. -->

<!-- Note that IE11 and older and some older versions of other browsers 
do not support loading external SVGs via the <use> element.
JS workarounds do exist, e.g. https://github.com/Keyamoon/svgxuse

More info:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22516712/svg-use-tag-with-external-reference-in-ie-11 -->

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="720" height="90" class="fill-blue">
<use xlink:href="external-svg-example.svg#g1"/>
</svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="720" height="90" class="fill-green">
<use xlink:href="external-svg-example.svg#g1"/>
</svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="720" height="90" class="fill-orange">
<use xlink:href="external-svg-example.svg#g1"/>
</svg>

<script src="svgxuse.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 720 90" width="720" height="90">
<style>
svg:root {
    /* "svg:root" is used so this rule won't interfere with other styles when this SVG is injected into a page via JS. */
    color: red;
    fill: currentColor;
    font-size:56px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
</style>
<g id="g1">
<text y="70" x="28">This is Our Test Text</text>
</g>
</svg>
```